# Handling the Request redirects in ASP.Net MVC 2 with ajax requests

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I have developed an ASP.NET MVC2 application and in that i have a login feature implemented.

I have other views that have ajax calls. At times, i find the ajax calls displaying the login page.

In an attempt to get rid of this problem, i have tried to simulate the situation, but the response code that i get from my application was `200` which is `OK`

I am using ASP.Net MVC2. Why am i getting 200, where i should be actually getting a 302 server redirect for login page redirection from my current view.

Guide me to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

> Why am i getting 200, where i should be actually getting a 302 server
>   redirect for login page redirection from my current view.

It's because jQuery follows the redirect and you end up with 200 and the login page. I would recommend you the [following article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) which illustrates a very elegant way to configure ASP.NET to send 401 status code for unauthenticated requests assuming this request was made using an AJAX call. Then your client code will look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/foo',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { foo: 'bar' },
    statusCode: {
        200: function (data) {
            alert('200: Authenticated');
            // Do whatever you was intending to do
            // in case of success
        },
        401: function (data) {
            alert('401: Unauthenticated');
            // Handle the 401 error here. You can redirect to 
            // the login page using window.location.href
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to that article. I suppose that the benefit that we gain out of this module is worth the work. But he says he haven't tested. If you have done so, let me know, else i'll test and update my comments in this post.